# Автоматическая установка приложений

Tags: установка, windows

Ищу программы которые умеют создавать пакеты тихой установки (установка ограничивается запуском пакета).
Уже пробовал:

- AppDeploy Repackager
- AiSnapshot

Первое не работает и постоянно вылетает.
Второе работает, но хотелось бы использовать что то другое, более удобное. Свежие версии его же вылетают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания msi-пакетов без диалогов, можно использовать практически любой установщик, в том числе и тот, что идет вместе с Visual Studio. Если нужен более тонкий инструмент, вполне подойдет [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), который используется самой Microsoft. Для Visual Studio есть плагин, позволяющий создавать проекты из самой студии.

Comment: Мне не подходят любые установщики. Я не знаю что программа устанавливает на диск.